# How to make an external javascript file knows its own host?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that in an external javascript file, can know the host of the file?

For example, if I have the site `http://hostOne.com/index.php`, the code of the file `index.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hostTwo.com/script/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need that in the file `test.js` can know the host `http://hostTwo.com`.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

or it can know the tag "script" which was called?, with this option I can analyzes the tag and get the "src" attribute. But I don't want to depend on the name of the file `test.js` and analyze all the tag `script` that contains the site.

***Solution based on the code of @Armi ***

Html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script class="jsbin"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script id="idscript" type="text/javascript" src="http://hostTwo.com/script/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>...</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code in JS

```
var 
     url = $('head').find('#idscript').attr('src'),
     host = url.replace(/(\/\/.*?\/).*/g, '$1');

console.log(host);
```

Comment: Why do you need that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to create a plugin to call files (html) template, like this http://encosia.com/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

Comment: That doesn't explain why a Javascript file needs to know where it was served from.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, by default the plugin look for template files in the same directory where it is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an idea (the snippet based on jQuery):

```
var yourScriptTag = $('head').find('script[src$="jquery-1.7.1.js"]').eq(0);
var theHostnameOfYourScript = $(yourScriptTag).attr('src').replace(/(http:\/\/.*?\/).*/g, '$1');

alert(theHostnameOfYourScript);
```

jsfiddle example: http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/XsJn8/

If you know the filename of your script (and if this is always the same and unique) you can use this snippet to get the hostname.

If this path is relative (and contains no host) you can get the hostname with a simple `location.hostname`

Comment: Yes, but I'm going to look for the ID of the script instead of the name of the script `$('head').find('#idcript').attr('src').replace(/(\/\/.*?\/).*/g, '$1')` http://jsbin.com/ovosow/edit#source

Comment: Of course, if you define to use this id, this is possible! But it should be a unique id to avoid conflicts with existing ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not possible. The content of the script is downloaded and after this it is fired. At this point the script "thinks" he is at your site.

Of course unless the host is hardcoded in the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because the JavaScript code is executed client-sided. You could propably parse it somehow out of your URL but, I don't think either that this is very useful and possible.

Answer (score -1):

Inside test.js, you can use :

```
var url = document.URL;
```

then parse the url result.

You can't make cross-site scripting, so if you need more sophisticated stuff, you could write your javascript in php and call :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hostTwo.com/script/test.php"></script>
```

But that's not standard.
Anyway,, the solution is on the server, with a designed proxy.

Comment: `document.URL` doesn't return the requested path! It returns the url of the document which has included the javascript!

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood part of the question.