# Javascript Get Hostname of File Host

Tags: javascript, hostname

Although [this question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/get-host-name-in-javascript), it is not what I am looking for.

Let's say on HostA.com I include a script from HostB.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hostb.com/script.js">
```

When **script.js** runs, I need to get the name of HostB (let's assume it can change). If I use:

```
var hostName = window.location.hostname;
```

It will return **HostA.com** rather than **HostB.com** obviously because that is where the the `window` object is scoped.

How can I get the name of HostB from within the script? Do I have to locate the `<script>` element in the DOM and parse the `src` attribute or is there a better way?

## **EDIT**

Yes, it is on my server, but may be on other servers as well. I am developing a javascript plugin and am trying to make absolute paths so it doesn't try to reference files on the server including the plugin.

Comment: If it's your server, you have access to that on the serverside, and can just output it into the script file that is served to the other site.

Comment: *"Do I have to locate the <script> element in the DOM and parse the src attribute"* yes, that's basically it.

Comment: *sigh* I hope ECMAScript 6 has something to address this.

Comment: So you want to put code INSIDE the script from the other host that figures out what host it is on?

Comment: You could access the script tag like so -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script#answer-3326554

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes. I'm using a CDN version of `require.js` to load a js file which contains plugin functionality. Some of it's dependencies require assets to be loaded and if I load them with relative paths, it assumes HostA rather than HostB (where the files are actually located). So I need to dynamically determine the hostname of HostB to avoid having to update the script anytime it is placed on a new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am loading the script with **RequireJS** which looks something like this:

```
<script data-main="http://hostb.com/js/app/main.js" src="http://hostb.com/js/vendor/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I figured out, with help from @adeneo that I can do something like this:

```
$('script[data-main*="/js/app/main.js"]').attr('data-main')
```

Which returns:

```
http://hostb.com/js/app/main.js
```

And I can parse it for the hostname.

```
var url = $('script[data-main*="/main.js"]').attr('data-main');
parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = url;
host = parser.hostname;
```

Thanks for the suggestions and nudge in the right direction!

## **BREAKING NEWS**

Turns out their is an easier way for anyone using RequireJS (who finds this question in search) and needs to be able to load absolute URL's with the script host:

```
var myCssPath = require.toUrl('css/mystyles.css');
```

That builds an absolute path using the hostname of the server running!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how: first off, include this as the first line of your script. I know it is a comment. Do it anyways

```
//BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHAAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFFGGGILIKEPI
```

next, use this function inside of that script to determine the host

```
function findHost(){
    var scripts=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var thisScript=null;
    for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
        if(scripts[i].innerHTML.indexOf('//BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHAAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFFGGGILIKEPI')!==-1)
            var thisScript=scripts[i];
    }
    var urlParser=document.createElement('a');
    urlParser.href=thisScript.getAttribute('src');
    return urlParser.hostname;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this method more reliable than mine?

Comment: no, it isn't, yours is probably better but I didn't know you were able to add attributes to your script.

Comment: This method is more reliable if you don't have any control over the code on hostA

Answer (score 0):

To omit using the hostname twice (as you described in your 'accepted answer') I implemented the solution this as follows:

HTML on **HostA.com**:

```
<script data-main="my_embed_id" src="http://hostb.com/js/vendor/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

require.js on **HostB.com**:

```
// get host where this javascript runs
var url = $('script[data-main="my_embed_id"]').attr('src');
var hostb = url.replace(/(\/\/.*?\/).*/g, '$1');
```

Which returns:

```
http://hostb.com
```

Inspired by: [How to make an external javascript file knows its own host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211339/how-to-make-an-external-javascript-file-knows-its-own-host)